# T-SQL to get most recent related record in many to many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, relationship

This seems like it should be relatively (no pun intended) easy to do, but I just can't get my mind around it. I have three tables, joined in a many-to-many relationship. A main "Issues" table, a "Statuses" table (lookup table indicating the name/description of different statuses: 'Open', 'In Progress', 'Closed', etc.), and a middle "IssuesStatuses" table to allow multiple statuses over time for the primary "Issues" record. I'm trying to write the T-SQL to get a list of "Issues", along with the most recent StatusName, based on the most recent related record in the IssuesStatuses table. Here's what the tables look like:

[Issues] table:
    - IssueID (PK)
    - IssueName
    - IssueDescription
    etc.

[IssuesStatuses] table:
    - IssuesStatusesID (PK)
    - IssueID (FK)
    - StatusID (FK)
    - IssuesStatusDate

[Statuses] table:
    - StatusID (PK)
    - StatusName

Users will add multiple records (for the same IssueID) to the IssuesStatuses table as they update the status of the main Issues record. So this query should get the [Issues] record, the most recent status for this record from the [IssuesStatuses] table, and the associated StatusName record from the [Statuses] table that's associated with that IssuesStatuses record. I'm pretty sure I need subquery(ies), and/or Max(StatusDate) functions, but I start writing too complicated nested subqueries when I attempt this in the SQL.

Does this make sense? Can someone please assist me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statuses are what is referred to as a slowly changing dimension.  One way to deal with these is to have an "effective" and "end" date for the records.  With `EffDate` and `EndDate`, the query that you want would be quite easy, either:

```
select *
from IssueStatus ist
where EndDate is NULL
```

or

```
where EndDate = '9999-01-01' -- or whatever your far out future date is
```

The downside is that inserting a new status requires two steps:

1. Set the `EndDate` of the current status
2. Insert a new record

You would typically encapsulate this logic in a stored procedure or trigger.

Given your data structure, you can get the most recent status by using `not exists`:

```
select ist.*
from IssueStatus ist
where not exists (select 1
                  from IssueStatus ist2
                  where ist2.issueId = ist.issueId and
                        ist2.IssueStatusDate > ist.IssueStatusDate
                 )
```

The logic is "Get me all rows from `IssueStatus` where the given Issue has no later status date."  That is equivalent to saying:  "Get me the row with the maximum date."  But for some reason, the database engine will do a good job optimizing this query when you have an index on `IssueStatus(IssueId, IssueStatusDate)`.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely consider adding the EndDate field to the table; the database isn't in production yet. From just looking at your last example (I'm not in SSMS now), I'm guessing I can join **ist** to the lookup table (Statuses) to get the pretty name of the Status?

Comment: @TheDudeDude . . . Yes.  I should have added to the answer "I'm only showing the part using the `IssueStatus` table but all the queries can be modified with join's to the other tables."